# Is it ok to ask a question again, over one year after it was left unanswered?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I've asked quite a number of question here on superuser, and a few of them never got answered. That's perfectly understandable (I'm still amazed at the number of questions that *do* get answered), [but one of those](https://superuser.com/questions/80024/how-do-you-change-the-number-of-visible-windows-in-each-superbar-icon) is turning 1 year old and I'd love to celebrate its birthday by squashing it.

**If an old (unanswered) question is still bugging me, even one year after being asked, is it okay to ask it again?**

Is it ok if I rephrase it, add more screenshots, etc?

Comment: It's OK to bump it, especially if you added more information to make it easier to answer. You could always jump into our chat room, so you can ask others to have another look at it too ;-)

Comment: @Ivo Flipse: Do I have to comment in order to bump it? Or will it get bumped just by editing?

Comment: It will get bumped by editing, but in my experience having attention in the chat room is far superior as it's crowded by those who attention you want in the first place ;-)

Comment: Good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I figure your best option is to edit your question to make it better by adding more information, screenshots, etc; making sure the wording is clear and consice and, ideally, you might want to consider adding a bouty to the question.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 for adding a bounty -- that's precisely what they are for!